# Is it possible to put a hole through an nGon without splitting the faces

Tags: mesh

I made these holes with "knife project", extruded the hole with "PunchIt" and tested with 3D-toolBox". The two highlighted faces are the non-flat faces as reported by 3D-toolBox.  The split occurred after "knife project". I have tried to repair the faces but always end up with split faces. eg. I removed edges and faces and tried replacing faces with "F" (Fill) and option+"F"(new face).
Maybe I should start with a square hole and use Quads and subD. Is it possible to put a hole through faces without splitting them?
[image]

Comment: A face must be defined by a single path of vertices, so it can't have a hole in Blender.

Comment: Yes, that does answer my question and thank you very much for taking the time to answer it.

Comment: @Barrie As Markus already said it is not possible to create holes without the connecting edges. What I sometimes to do make it at least looking a bit "nicer" is splitting the face horizontally or vertically before creating a hole so that the hole uses these straight edges automatically.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann especially if those edges are aligned with the topology of the hole, because then insetting the two ngons will produce even quads near the hole (and such insetting is nice for smooth shading, or even insetting twice for subdivision surface modifier)